# Tensorproduct and properties of maps

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

I have a problem with the following:

Let be $ V $ and $ W $ vectorspaces over $ \mathbb{K} $ and choose a base $ (v_i)_{i\in I} $  for $ V $ and a base $ (w_j)_{j\in J} $  for $ W $.

Now define a vectorspace $ V\otimes W $ of finite linearcombinations of the formal expressions $ v_i\otimes w_j $. More precise:

Consider the vectorspace over $ \mathbb{K} $ $$ \operatorname{Map}(I\times J, \mathbb{K}):=\{\tau:\space I\times J \to \mathbb{K}\} $$ and its subspace $$ V\otimes W:=\{\tau:\space I\times J \to \mathbb{K}:\space \tau(i,j)\neq 0 \space \text{for a finete number of}\space  (i,j)\in I\times J\}. $$

**Now my question:** Why are $ v_i\otimes w_j\in V\otimes W $ those kind of maps such that they take only for $ (i,j) $ the value 1 and else 0? I cannot see why this property holds for those maps.

Comment: I don't understand your question, anyway the definition of the tensor product Is the quotient of that space by the "bilinear relations"